# insert string value with apostrophe

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sqlite

Consider a string with an apostrophe that needs to be inserted into a SQLite table.

```
INSERT INTO myTable ( table_Title TEXT ) VALUES ( 'world's' )
```

How can you markup or escape the apostrophe in the value  in the `INSERT` statement?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html

You should not be passing input directly into a query as a string like this.  Not only is it a nuisance, it's also vulnerable to SQL injection attacks, which may not be a big problem for a Mac app, but is still a bad idea when you have Prepared Statements at your disposal.  Prepared Statements ensure the underlying database reads the actual, unmodified, input values safely.

For your specific example (error checking removed for brevity/clarity):

```
sqlite3 *db;
sqlite3_open("test.db", &db);

// Create a prepared statement
sqlite3_stmt *stmt;
const char *sql = "INSERT INTO myTable (table_Title TEXT) VALUES (?)";
sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sql, -1, &stmt, NULL);

// Bind the parameter (safely)
sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 1, "world's", -1, NULL);

// Execute the prepared statement
sqlite3_step(stmt);
```

(Untested, but you get the idea).

Answer (score 2):

You can use '' instead of a single apostrophe .
Example to insert haven't 
`Insert into table_name values('haven''t');`

Reference : https://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q14